# Polynomial data and R's glm()

Tags: r, glm

How can you get R's glm() to match polynomial data? I've tried several iterations of 'family=AAA(link="BBB")' but I can't seem to get trivial predictions to match.

For example, please help with R's glm to match polynomial data

```
x=seq(-6,6,2)
y=x*x
parabola=data.frame(x,y)
plot(parabola)
model=glm(y~x,dat=parabola)
test=data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,2))
test$y=predict(model,test)
plot(test)
```

The plot(parabola) looks as expected, but I can find the incantation of glm() that will make plot(test) look parabolic.

Comment: You're fitting a linear model to non-linear data. Try adding a quadratic term. (And why do you feel it's necessary to glm in this case rather than lm?)

Comment: Thanks Joran. How can I add a quadratic term? What is the syntax? Using lm() would be OK - what is the correct lm() syntax to match polynomial data?

Comment: specifically, try `model=lm(y~poly(x,2),dat=parabola)` for a quadratic fit (you can increase the order of the polynomial, but fitting higher-order polynomials can be dangerous/unstable/disrecommended)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to step back and start to think about a model and how you represent this in R. In your example, `y` is a quadratic function of `x`, so you need to include `x` and `x^2` in the model formula, i.e. as predictors you need to estimate the effect of `x` and `x^2` on the response given the data to hand.

If `y` is Gaussian, conditional upon the model, then you can do this with `lm()` and either

```
y ~ x + I(x^2)
```

or

```
y ~ poly(x, 2)
```

In the first, we wrap the quadratic term in `I()` as the `^` operator has a special meaning (not its mathematical one) in an R model formula. The latter version gives orthogonal polynomials and hence the `x` and `x^2` terms won't be correlated which can help with fitting, however in some cases interpreting the coefficients is trickier with `poly()`.

Putting it all together we have (note that I add some random error to `y` so as to not predict it perfectly as the example I use is more common in reality):

```
x <- seq(-6 ,6 ,2)
y <- x^2 + rnorm(length(x), sd = 2)
parabola <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = parabola)

plot(parabola)
lines(fitted(mod) ~ x, data = parabola, col = "red")
```

The plot produced is:

[image]

An additional issue is whether `y` is Gaussian? If `y` can't be negative (i.e. a count), and/or is discrete, modelling using `lm()` is going to be wrong. That's where `glm()` might come in, by which you might fit a curve without needing `x^2` (although if the data really are a parabola, then `x` on its own isn't going to fit the response), as there is an explicit transformation of the data from the linear predictor on to the scale of the response.

It is better to think about the properties of the data and the sort of model you want to fit and then build up the degree of polynomial within that modelling framework, rather than jumping in a trying various incantations to simply curve fit the data.

Answer (score 0):

The match is now perfect. A slightly more interesting parabola:

```
x=seq(-16,16,2)
y= 4*x*x + 10*x + 6
parabola=data.frame(x,y)
plot(parabola)
model=lm(y~poly(x,2),dat=parabola)
summary(model)
test=data.frame(x=seq(-15,15,2))
test$y=predict(model,test)
points(test,pch=3)
```

An amateur (like me) might expect the coefficients of the model to be (4,10,6) to match 4*x*x + 10*x + 6

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), data = parabola)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.646e-13 -8.748e-14 -3.691e-14  4.929e-14  6.387e-13 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 3.900e+02  5.192e-14 7.511e+15   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)1 4.040e+02  2.141e-13 1.887e+15   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)2 1.409e+03  2.141e-13 6.581e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.141e-13 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 2.343e+31 on 2 and 14 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Why would the coefficients be (390,404,1409)?

Comment: model=lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE),dat=parabola) gives the expected coefficients. As Gavin pointed out, interpreting the coefficients of orthogonal polynomials is tricky.